# Convert android wav file with SOX

Tags: android, audio, wav, sox

Hi I use android to generate a wav file which is upload before to my server. In order to play this WAV file in a telephony system I must convert it to 16000 bitrate. The problem is the wav generate by android because I have this error :

```
WAVE: RIFF header not found
```

here is my sox script :

```
# sox -t wav input.wav output.wav
```

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE : The wav created by android give me that : ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, 3GPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the last version of ffmpeg (build 03-Feb-2014) the following command work :

```
ffmpeg -i 2353-1389698676.wav -ar 8000 -b 16k convert/2353-1389698676-convert.wav
```

So SOX fail for this kind of conversion...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your WAV file doesn't have header data. WAV files are a type of RIFF file and they require header data before you write the audio data. Here is a link to a page that details how the format of WAV file headers. Just add the header, set all the values to match your content, and that should work.

Link : http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html

Comment: Thanks David, the WAV file is generated by android recording to you know if I can add those RIFF header after?

Comment: How are you creating the files?

Comment: I use a phonegap app which use android core audio recording... But without any header...

Comment: Oh. Well I don't know about PhoneGap. I do it by saving the audio to a stream, then writing the header to the file, then the audio stream after that.

Comment: Do you know if I can add those Riff header after the wav generation? So that I could use sox or ffmpeg to change the bitrate?